# DBMS: ER Diagram - One to many relationship with descriptive attribute

Tags: database, relational-database, erd

I have the following ERD:

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2t74.png)

I need to convert this into relational schema but I have some doubts on where the attribute "since" would belong. I know how 1-M relationships work but I am confused by the attribute since. Does a new table Company-Employee need to be created where it would hold the Company id, emp id and since?

Please let me know thank you.

Comment: Assuming that an Employee cannot belong to more than one Company at the same time, you store company id & since as part of Employee table.

Comment: @naresh can you please explain in further details on why is that better than creating a new table? Thank you.

Comment: you can create a new table as well if you think that Employee exists without belonging to a company. Relationship between Employee and Company and relationship attributes can be captured in that new table

Answer (score 0):

As you have diagrammed it, the Since attribute describes the relationship, not the employee or the company.  There's nothing wrong with that, although some experts maintain that attributes must describe entities and not relationships.

When you go to design a relational schema, both entities and relationships become relations (or, as I prefer, "tables").  Your only question seems to be whether there has to be a junction table between the Employee table and the Company table.

You can get away with just two tables.    You can stuff both the CompanyId and the Since columns into the Employee table, because they will be single valued.  There may be other considerations that lead you to decompose the two tables, but you don't have to do it just to represent the data.